# Get the Bearer Token from Network Tab of Chrome Dev Tool using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I've got an API but to use it I need to Login to a Web Portal first, get the Bearer Token from the Network Tab (Within request Headers of one of the request) and use that token to Access the API

For Logging into the Portal, I can manage with Selenium but is there a way to get the access token from the Network tab from within Selenium?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome